# Attribute not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this ruby code for radio buttons in my user `new` form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile, Profile.new do |t| %>
 <div class ="field">
    <%= t.label :type, "Are you an artist or listener?" %><br />
    <p> Artist: <%= t.radio_button :type, "artist" %></p>
    <p> Listener: <%= t.radio_button :type, "listener" %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to set the `type` attribute of my Profile model. However, type is not being set and is defaulting to `nil`. I tried creating this `create` method in my profile controller but it didn't work:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  if params[:profile_attributes][:type] == "artist"
    @profile.type = "artist"
  elsif params[:profile_attributes][:type] == "listener"
    @profile.type = "listener"
  end
end
```

How can I get `type` to be set to "artist" or "listener" correctly?

UPDATE:

I get this error: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to access it like this:

```
params[:user][:profile_attributes][:type]
```

Your view should look something like:

```
<%= form_for(setup_user(@user)) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
    <%= profile.label :username %>
    <br/>
    <%= profile.text_field :username %>
```

and in your helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  def setup_user(user)
    user.tap do |u|
      u.build_profile if u.profile.nil?
    end
  end
```

This is just an example.

Comment: thanks but I still can't seem to get `type` to be set... could you please show me the form code and controller code I should be using... I must be getting something wrong

Comment: what about the controller code to set `type`? Still can't have it set for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
   <%= f.fields_for :profile, @user.build_profile(:type => "Artist") do |t| %>
```

Comment: and can I also get rid of that `before_create :build_profile` callback then?

Comment: and I should be setting type automatically to artist? this doesn't seem to work..

Comment: capitalized? the string, right? also, can I get rid of that controller code? still can't get `type` set :/

Comment: I believe type is attr_protected in rails 3, which means :type => 'ClassName' will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My First Answer was bad:

Make sure your type strings are CamelCased. Also, I believe type is attr_protected meaning you can not set it via attr_accesible.

Something like this may get you going in the right direction:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @profile = profile_type.new(pararms[:profile])
    if @profile.save(params[:profile])
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

private

  def profile_type
    params[:profile][:type].classify.constantize if %w(Artist Listener).include? params[:profile][type]
  end

end
```

Comment: Correct about type. Renaming the attribute _type_ to _profile_type_ in will bypass this concern. _type_ attribute is used for single table inheritance (STI) and should not be used when creating attributes in your model. See the "Single table inheritance" section in the documentation for more information http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html